# How to get End Event of YouTube Video

Tags: events, video, youtube

I am working on site where I have one image. Clicking on that image it opens a jQuery dialogue. In this dialogue i open iframe and src of iFrame is YouTube Videos URL. I want that when video stops, page should automatically redirect to the contact us Page.

Below is the JavaScript Code that I used to open a dialogue when someone clicks on image of video.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                position:['',100],
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "fade",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });
            $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
               $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
               $("#vieoplayId").attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/T6DJcgm3wNY?autoplay=1");
            });
       });
```

Below is the HTML Code

```
<div id="dialog">
   <div id="dialog1">
      <iframe  id="vieoplayId"  src="about:blank" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
     </div>
</div>                                    
 <div class="video_container">
    <img src="../images/img1.jpg" id="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">
 </div>
```

Comment: Check the Youtube Player API. Here's the link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples